# remove all key value pairs from array of objects except for a specific key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects

```
const myArr = [
  {k1: 1, k2: 1, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}
]
```

I am trying to filter these, I don't need to use filter but that's just what I'm currently doing.

`const filteredObj = myArr.filter(item => item.k2 === 1)`

but I would like to only keep one key value pair. For example

`console.log(myArr) => {k2: 1}`

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map()` with object destructuring and property shorthand syntax:

```js
const myArr = [
  {k1: 1, k2: 1, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}, 
  {k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3, k4: 4}
]

const filteredObj = myArr.filter(item => item.k2 === 1).map(({k2}) => ({k2}));

console.log(filteredObj);
```